# Change for loop index in Kotlin

Tags: loops, for-loop, kotlin

How can I modify the loop variable in Kotlin?

For my particular case, I have a for-loop in which, for certain conditions, I want to skip the next iteration:

```
for(i in 0..n) {
  // ...
  if(someCond) {
    i++ // Skip the next iteration
  }
}
```

However, when I try this, I'm told that "val cannot be reassigned".

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You can't mutate the current element, you would need to use a `while` loop instead:

```
var i = 0
while (i <= n) {
    // do something        
    
    if (someCond) {
        i++ // Skip the next iteration
    }

    i++
}
```

What are you trying to do? There is a chance there is a more idiomatic way to do this.

If you could restructure this logic to skip the *current* iteration, why not use `continue`:

```
for (i in 0..n) {
    if (someCond) {
        continue
    }
    // ...
}
```

Side note: `..` ranges are inclusive, so to loop through e.g. a list of size `n` you usually need `0..(n - 1)` which is more simply done with [`until`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.ranges/until.html): `0 until n`.

---

In your specific case, you can use [`windowed`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/windowed.html) (Kotlin 1.2):

```
list.asSequence().filter { someCond }.windowed(2, 1, false).forEach { 
    val (first, second) = it
    // ...
}
```

`asSequence` will convert the list into a `Sequence`, removing the overhead of `filter` and `windowed` creating a new `List` (as they will now both return `Sequence`s).

If you want the next pair to not include the last element of the previous pair, use `windowed(2, 2, false)` instead.

Comment: The task at hand involves iterating through adjacent pairs of elements...so the loop works with indices i and i+1 together. The condition happens if I discover something about i+1 that means it shouldn't be looked at anymore.

Comment: I might suggest that your while loop could be a little more succinct by initializing i to -1 and making the condition (++i <= n). This would also ensure no branch accidentally forgets to increment.

Comment: Not exactly. Doing that would loop through the pairs, (0,1), (2,3), etc., but it would never work with the pair (1,2).

Comment: I must say, they made this unnecessarily complicated. Imo one of the few areas where Kotlin has rather regressed than evolved.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like what you're really trying to do is iterate a sliding window of size 2 over a list. If you're using kotlin 1.2 or later, you might use the `List.windowed()` library function.

For example, to consider each pair of adjacent elements, but discarding the ones where the second of the pair is negative, you would do:

```
val list = listOf(1, 2, 3, -4, -5, 6)
list.windowed(2,1).filter { it[1] > 0 }.apply(::println)
```

Which would print out

```
[[1, 2], [2, 3], [-5, 6]]
```

having skipped the pairs [3, -4] and [-4, -5]

Answer (score -1):

while many people described the problem and suggested a solution with advanced methods or operators which I think is not suitable for beginners.
I applied a fix on the code so that you can understand it easily and it just uses a while loop instead of for loop.if you could understand it and found it useful please consider accepting the answer

```
fun main(args:Array<String>){

    var alphabet = mutableListOf(
            'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm',
            'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'
    )
    var key = "keyword"
    println(key)
    for (i in key.indices)
    {
        var j = 0
        while (j < alphabet.size) {
            if (key[i] == alphabet[j]){
                alphabet.removeAt(j)     // 1. this line have error
            } else j++
        }
    }
    print(alphabet)
}
```

Comment: The top answer _starts_ with a while loop -- one that is simpler and clearer than yours.