# I am getting the val cannot be reassigned compile time error. But I have declared the variable as `var` only

Tags: kotlin

`val` cannot be reassigned compile time error `var` variable. Can't we change the array value?

Error

> Array.kt:11:3: error: val cannot be reassigned

Code:

```
import java.util.Scanner

fun main(args: Array< String>){
  println("Enter the no")
  val scanner = Scanner(System.`in`)
  var nos = Array<Int>(5){0}

  var i : Int = 1
  for (i in 1..3){
    nos[i] = scanner.nextInt()
     i = i+1
  }

  println("Given values $nos")
}
```

Comment: you don't need to manually increment `i` or manually set `i` in a for loop

Comment: You do not need to declare var i : Int = 1 as it'll be declared for you in the loop. Nor do you need the i = i+1 inside the loop for that matter.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change for loop index in Kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48458801/change-for-loop-index-in-kotlin)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `for (i in 1..3) ...` statement redefines `i` for the scope of its body, where it becomes a `val` (it's actually a separate variable that shadows the `i` declared outside the loop).

You can fix the code by using different names for these variables, or, in your case, by simply removing `var i: Int = 1` and `i = i + 1`:

```
val scanner = Scanner(System.`in`)

var nos = Array<Int>(5) { 0 }

for (i in 1..3) {
    nos[i] = scanner.nextInt()
}

println("Given values $nos")
```

**UPD** (answering to the comment): You can iterate in the opposite direction or using a non-unit step by building a progression with functions `downTo` and `step`, both described [here in the reference](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/ranges.html#utility-functions).

Comment: You left the build-breaking `i = i + 1`.

Comment: Thanks for explanation. Don't I get the same error again? Bcoz, again we are incrementing the value of `i` inside the `for` . So I have to remove that statement also. If so, my second question how to I decrement or do `i = i + 2` in the `for` loop.

Comment: Thanks @hotkey . Works fine

Answer (score 3):

```
var i : Int = 1
for (i in 1..3){
  nos[i] = scanner.nextInt()
  i = i+1
}
```

In this code you declared not one, but two variables with the name `i` because the `for` header creates its own declaration. Within the loop, only the version declared in the `for` header is visible, and that one is a `val` by definition.

Having said that, I'm unclear on what you were trying to achieve since everything looks like it would work just the way you want it without trying to update `i` in the loop.